# How to add a shared input field for multiple forms in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I have a page includes multiple forms:

```
<%= simple_form_for :data, url: apples_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :apple %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
<%= simple_form_for :data, url: pears_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :pear %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now I want to add a shared input field above these forms, called `provider_id`. And no matter which form is submitted, it will includes the input of `provider_id`.

I don't want to add this field to each of forms because I only need it appears once in the page.

Comment: Unless i'm missing something , isn't it good idea to pass provider_id in form_url as - `apples_path(provide_id: "xyz")` ? If it's concern for only one field.

Comment: @Gabbar the `provide_id` is from user input

Answer (score 0):

Put the field in both forms and make it hidden on one form.

```
 <%= simple_form_for :data, url: apples_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :provider_id %>
      <%= f.input :apple %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
    <%= simple_form_for :data, url: pears_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden :provider_id %>
      <%= f.input :pear %>
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating one field (txt1) above these two forms. And have two hidden fields inside forms. So on some event for the field (txt1) onkeyup for example in javascript every input to that  field copy also to hidden fields. In that way you will have value you need inside both form, but only one file will be visible for both forms on page?